Power Query: Get data from another table matching multi conditions
Tried to find a solution within other posts, no luck.
In Power query, I have two tables I want to match with conditions.
Here are the tables:
(I am having a problem with tables editing, so the screenshot of tables attached)
TABLE1



Order
Seq
Op




7000455
4
40


3010445
0
550


3010445
0
120



TABLE2



Order
Seq
Op
Conf




7000455
4
50
20631586


3010445
0
510
21576057


3010445
0
540
21576060


3010445
0
570
21576059



Now, I want to get [Conf] value for each row in TABLE1 from TABLE2 with conditions:

TABLE1[Order] = TABLE2[Order]
TABLE1[Seq] = TABLE2[Seq]
TABLE1[Op] > TABLE2[Op]
If more than one record found, I need the closest (max) [Op] to the one from TABLE1

*null *if conditions not fulfilled:
TABLE3 (result)



Order
Seq
Op
Conf




7000455
4
40
null


3010445
0
550
21576060


3010445
0
120
null



Hope the problem explanation is clear.
Now, I tried the below M-code, but this is (....) where I stuck:
    = let
        Source = TABLE1,
        TABLE2 = Table.SelectColumns(TableX, {"Order", "Seq", "Op", "Conf"}),
        TABLE3 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Conf2", (i) => (Table.SelectRows(TABLE2, each (.....)) [Conf]{}, type number)
    in
        TABLE3


This matches order and Seq, finds all rows with Op>Op, sorts on Op, takes the first row, and extracts the [Conf] field
let Source = Table1,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Conf",  (x)=>
    try Table.Sort(Table.SelectRows(Table2, each x[Order]=[Order] and x[Seq]=[Seq] and x[Op]>[Op]),{{"Op", Order.Descending}}){0}[Conf]
    otherwise null)
in #"Added Custom"



Yes! Thank you! Small correction to the table with the column added (should be Table1 instead of Table2), but the logic works.
